# how to write nested condition using ternary operator in java?

Tags: java

Can we write like this using ternary operator? When I wrote like this I am getting error,Please help me.How can I write correct syntax?

```
(str.charAt(j)==c.charAt(k++)) ? break: k<len1 ? continue:break L1;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `break L1`?

Comment: @underdog the error is illegal start of expression and not a statement .

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator is a part of *expression* and its components must be *expressions* as well, not the *statements*. In this case you can easily use `if` stamement:

```
if (str.charAt(j)==c.charAt(k++)) 
    break;
else if (k<len1)
    continue;
else 
    break L1;
```

Or even simpler:

```
if (str.charAt(j)==c.charAt(k++)) 
    break;
if (k<len1)
    continue;
break L1;
```

Comment: ¿Would the downvoter care to comment? This seems like a perfectly valid answer to me!

Comment: @WaiHaLee Agree, but if you see a good perfectly valid answer, and you even care enough to comment on somebody downvoting it, then *why don't you upvote it yourself?*

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt — if I knew more about Java I would. I based my comment on C# knowledge.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Ok. I can tell you that in Java, like in C#, the ternary operator is an expression, so it cannot contain statements (just like `a == b || break` is invalid in Java/C#, although it's valid in some scripting languages that only copied a bit of syntax from C)

Comment: @Tagir Valeev thank you  but i wanted to experiment with ternary operator so i tried..

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - in that case you've convinced me. As I said, I'm not proficient in Java (though I could have checked somewhere like [this page on oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)). +1.

Answer (score 0):

[break](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) & continue are always used within a loop; You you might want to recheck your logic.

If you want to write a nested ternary operator the general syntax would be

```
boolean x=("a".equals("b"))? false: (("b".equals("c"))?true:false);
System.out.println(x);
```

Output

```
false
```